# why am i getting a typeError when i try running this function? how do i solve that?

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

```
    function medianOfArray(array) {
     var length = array.length;
    // Odd
     if (length % 2 == 1 ) {
     return array[Math .floor(length / 2 )];
     } else {
     // Even
     return (array[length / 2 ] + array[length / 2 - 1 ]) / 2 ;
     }
}
```

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: The error means that your `array` parameter is `undefined`. How are you calling your `medianOfArray` function?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: I am new to the platform. Thank you for the feedback.